# Asp.net menu with navbar style

Tags: css, asp.net, menu

I want to use bootstrap menu style in asp.menu but all my try not work.

the menu I want to use is

```
 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">web name </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.aspx">aboutus</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Portfolio
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Blog
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog5" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Other Pages
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the above menu is normal and it works fine [Example](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/services.html)

and the asp menu that i want to use is

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2">
         </asp:Menu>
```

I have to try to use the bootstrap in my asp.net menu as the following code:
in side div `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">`

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu51" 
    runat="server" 
    Orientation="Horizontal" 
    StaticDisplayLevels="1"
    StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
   DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2"
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10" 
    EnableViewState="false"


    StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="navbar-nav ml-auto" 
    StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="nav-link"
    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"

    DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" 
    DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="dropdown-item"


    IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
    SkipLinkText=""
    RenderingMode="List">


</asp:Menu>
```

the problem now is when I run my webpage the menu didn't take all style, you can check it, you will find that li tag didn't take the class name, so cloud anyone helps me in that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one man from other website give me a smart sulution, he uses asp:Repeater instead of asp:Menu, so I call the sitemap in the repeater and it's work fine,

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">web name </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu1" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li class='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes.Count == 0 ? "nav-item" : "nav-item dropdown" %>'>
                                        <asp:HyperLink CssClass="nav-link" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes.Count == 0 ? true : false %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                        <asp:HyperLink CssClass="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ID="navbarDropdownPortfolio" Visible='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes.Count == 0 ? false : true %>' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server" NavigateUrl='#'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HyperLink CssClass="dropdown-item" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </div>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and this work very fine
thanks for everyone